# How to install ivy in Spring Source Tools Suite (STS) / eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ant, ivy, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am a .net developer and new to Java/eclipse/STS.

I am trying to setup a development environment in STS (STS = eclipse + spring tools). I need to use ivy for dependency management as I need to have multiple projects involved.

The problem is that I am unable to get the STS environment integrate with ivy!

I have been reading a lot of blogs/tutorials etc. but most of them just talk about installing each product separately and not on how to integrate them.

Any help or good link to integrate/install ivy with STS is appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Regards
Ajay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your question, I am not exactly sure what you have tried and what you have not.  I am assuming that you have STS set up properly and are just looking at how to install the Ivy tooling into STS.  Ivy tooling is called IvyDE

The first thing to do is to make sure that the update site is correct.  Here is the correct update site for IvyDE:

```
http://www.apache.org/dist/ant/ivyde/updatesite
```

Add this update site to your install manager (Help -> Install new software...).  Then go through the steps to install.

If you have a version conflict or anything like that, please post the exact exception in your question.

Comment: Thank you Andrew! I tried doing that after posting this question, but the installation fails midway during the process. But I tried on my other laptop and it worked! Difference is that my new laptop (where i want to setup the environment) is Windows 7 (64 bit) and my old laptop is Windows XP (32 bit). I have copied over the 32 bit installation to my new machine and hope there will be no problems. Thank you !!

Comment: I don't know when it changed, but for anyone in the future the url has changed to: `http://www.apache.org/dist/ant/ivyde/updatesite`